# How to insert PivotItem at particular index in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am currently working with Pivot Control and I want to insert PivotItem at particular index based on List which I get from server. When I try below code get an exception

```
MWPivot.Items.Clear();
        if(MCSManager.Instance.MWMenuItemsList.MW_HEADER_LIST !=null)
        {
            List<SUBPARAM> mw_header_list = new List<SUBPARAM>();
            mw_header_list = MCSManager.Instance.MWMenuItemsList.MW_HEADER_LIST.SUB_PARAMS;
            if(mw_header_list.Any(header=>header.SP_CODE.Equals("SERVICE_REQUEST")))
            {
                SUBPARAM SR_SUB_PARAM = mw_header_list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.SP_CODE.Equals("SERVICE_REQUEST"));
                PivotItem service_requestPivotItem = new PivotItem();
                service_requestPivotItem.Header = SR_SUB_PARAM.SP_TITLE;
                Grid SR_Grid = new Grid();
                SR_Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                SR_Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

                ReportsSearchBox = new PhoneTextBox();
                ReportsSearchBox.Hint = "Search Reports";
                ReportsSearchBox.ActionIcon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/search.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                ReportsSearchBox.TextChanged += SearchReports;

                Grid.SetRow(ReportsSearchBox, 0);
                SR_Grid.Children.Add(ReportsSearchBox);

                reportsListBox = new ListBox();
                reportsListBox.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0);
                reportsListBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                reportsListBox.ItemContainerStyle = App.Current.Resources["GenericListBoxContainerStyle"] as Style;
                reportsListBox.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["MWReportsTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
                reportsListBox.SelectionChanged += reportsListBox_SelectionChanged;

                Grid.SetRow(reportsListBox, 1);
                SR_Grid.Children.Add(reportsListBox);

                service_requestPivotItem.Content = SR_Grid;
                var sr_index = mw_header_list.FindIndex(item => item.SP_CODE.Equals("SERVICE_REQUEST"));
//Get Exception on below line 
                MWPivot.Items.Insert(sr_index, service_requestPivotItem);
            }
```

The exception I get is *specified argument was out of the range of valid values. parameter name index*

Also, the order of index may differ for example , I may need to insert the above item at any index based on **mw_header_list** item index.

Please someone suggest how can I achieve my requirement ?

Comment: What is the value if sr_index and the  MWPivot.Items.Count when you get the exception?

Comment: MWPivot.Items.Count = 0 and sr_index = 0 for now, but it may differ based on mw_header_list parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to achieve what I wanted to do. Thanks@IgorKulman for motivating me.

Please find my code below

```
 MWPivot.Items.Clear();
        MCSProgressIndicator.ActivateProgressIndicator(MCSManager.Instance.currentTextParams.COMMON_PLEASE_WAIT);
        if (MCSManager.Instance.MWMenuItemsList.MW_HEADER_LIST !=null)
        {
            mw_header_list = new List<SUBPARAM>();
            mw_header_list = MCSManager.Instance.MWMenuItemsList.MW_HEADER_LIST.SUB_PARAMS;
            foreach(var header in mw_header_list)
            {
                PivotItem mwPivotItem = new PivotItem()
                {
                    Name=header.SP_CODE,
                    Header=header.SP_TITLE
                };
                createViewForPivotItem(mwPivotItem, header.SP_CODE);
                MWPivot.Items.Add(mwPivotItem);
                //MWPivot.SelectionChanged += MWPivot_SelectionChanged;
            }
            if (userSettings.Contains("SelectedIndex"))
                MWPivot.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(userSettings["SelectedIndex"].ToString());
            MCSProgressIndicator.deactivateProgressIndicator();
        }
```

Hope it helps someone. I just added Pivot dynamic by using a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to add an item to a position that does not exists. If for example you have a collection with 3 items, you can only add new items to positions  0,1,2,3 not 4 or higher.

So add a check to your code to handle this and deal accordingly (adding the item at the end if the index is too high, or something)

```
if (sr_index>MWPivot.Items.Count)
{
    MWPivot.Items.Add(service_requestPivotItem);
} else {
    MWPivot.Items.Insert(sr_index, service_requestPivotItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks will it work in case "Suppose I have 4 items in mw_header_list" and i create UI and add items but will it get inserted at particular position ? I want to achieve that.

Comment: What about just trying for yourself? StackOverflow is not here to solve you problem, but to help you solve your problem.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but it is not giving me expected results that I want.

Comment: So make it do what you want, you are the programmer, the computer is your slave